# What's the outcome when there's a double knockout?

Tags: competition, terminology

What's the result of the fight when there's a double knockout (e.g. both fighters hit each other at the same time or sth)? A draw? Both lose? Both win? :P

I intentionally don't specify the concrete discipline - if the outcomes are different in different disciplines - please mention all of them.

Comment: Welcome to the site! An interesting question but it borders on asking for a list... Narrowing it by style might be better. Are there actually any examples of that happening?

Comment: Yeah, just google "double knockout" and you should get a list of videos and maybe other results.

Comment: This is not a good question unless we specify a style. The answer is, shall we say, somewhat influenced by the ruleset. A simultaneous strike in JKA pointfighting is handled differently from an actual double KO in MMA.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann What do you suggest then? That I create as many different threads as there are styles? Ridiculous.

Comment: You're asking the answers to list every answer for every style. What about double knockouts in aikido? Boxing? Fencing? What does the question even mean in those contexts? A "double knockout" isn't even in the same stadium as a "double touch" in fencing or a "simultaneous strike" in kendo or...whatever happens in aikido.

Comment: One thing that narrows it down - I'm only asking about knockouts. If there are no knockouts in some discipline then my question doesn't concern it. Also, I'm satisfied with Juann Strauss's answer.

Comment: Without a specific style this question is too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no winner, it's a tie. Depending on the style, there might be an extra round or sudden death, or the officials may get technical and look at points from the current and previous matches to determine the winner. In some instances, like when the match was the final round of the competition, the officials *may* decide to award both fighters 1st place, but name neither of them the champion.

If I were the head judge on that day, I'd let both fighters rest for an hour or two and have a rematch. Unless either one sustained a concussion, in which case see above.